# Wordpress codex: php for URL of current user avatar

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, avatar, codex

I was wondering if there is a way to get the URI/URL of the current logged-in user's avatar in wordpress? I found this as a way to generate a shortcode to insert the current user avatar using get_avatar (below php to be placed in theme functions.php):

```
<?php

function logged_in_user_avatar_shortcode() {
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
return get_avatar( $current_user->ID );
}
}
add_shortcode('logged-in-user-avatar', 'logged_in_user_avatar_shortcode');

?>
```

However, this returns the whole image including attributes (img src, class, width, height, alt). I want to return just the URL alone because i have already set all the attributes for my image in the template.

Trying to make something like this:

```
<img src="[shortcode-for-avatar-url]" class="myclass" etc >
```

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: It's ugly, but there's an answer [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59442/how-do-i-get-the-avatar-url-instead-of-an-html-img-tag-when-using-get-avatar)

Comment: As far as I can tell, WP doesn't have an option for returning the URL only. Or at least, the Codex doesn't appear to mention it. So the above link it probably your best bet.

Comment: Oh, damn. I tried to use the first solution on the link, it almost worked but always shows me the same template avatar for every user.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_match` to find the URL:

```
function logged_in_user_avatar_shortcode()
{
    if ( is_user_logged_in() )
    {
        global $current_user;
        $avatar = get_avatar( $current_user->ID );
        preg_match("/src=(['\"])(.*?)\1/", $avatar, $match);
        return $match[2];
    }
}
add_shortcode('logged-in-user-avatar', 'logged_in_user_avatar_shortcode');
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the idea. Sadly didn't work though.  <img src="[logged-in-user-avatar]" class="img-circle"> in pages produces :     <img src="" class="img-circle">. Any ideas? (PS i didn't forget to put the new code into the functions.php)

Comment: @user1527123 change `return $match[2];` to `echo $match[2];`

Comment: nope, that didnt fix it either. Getting the same, just nothing returned. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a PHP function to get a users gravatar in recent WordPress installations, if WordPress is less than version 2.5 my function used a different way of retrieving a users gravatar. A slightly modified version that simply outputs a users gravatar URI can be found below.

```
// Fallback for WP < 2.5
global $post;

$gravatar_post_id = get_queried_object_id();
$gravatar_author_id = get_post_field('post_author', $gravatar_post_id) || $post->post_author;//get_the_author_meta('ID');
$gravatar_email = get_the_author_meta('user_email', $gravatar_author_id);

$gravatar_hash = md5(strtolower(trim($gravatar_email)));
$gravatar_size = 68;
$gravatar_default = urlencode('mm');
$gravatar_rating = 'PG';
$gravatar_uri = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/'.$gravatar_hash.'.jpg?s='.$gravatar_size.'&amp;d='.$gravatar_default.'&amp;r='.$gravatar_rating.'';

echo $gravatar_uri; // URI of GRAVATAR
```

Comment: Thanks, but im using latest version wordpress, and im looking for local avatar (as uploaded by user or default template), not gravatar. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old question, but for anyone looking, there's a more concise way to get the avatar url with `get_avatar_url()`. ([More info here.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar_url/))

```
global $current_user; wp_get_current_user();
$avatar_url = get_avatar_url( $current_user->ID );
```